# x<x<x seems to be true (it isn't), according to calculator logic test

Tags: calculator

I punched into my TI-84 the following, using the "<" function from the logic test:
$$1<1<1$$ I'm sure that this statement must be false, for example it's false that $x<x$, so why does the calculator evaluate the expression as true, particularly if I also tried $1<1$ and it returned the right answer, that the statement is false?

According to the convention used by the calculator, a false statement evaluates to 0 and a true one evaluates to 1.

Comment: $x \leq x \leq x$ is true. NOT $x < x < x$. If this question is coming from the squeeze theorem, then the key point is that limits preserve *weak*, not *strict* inequality, so  if $a_n < b_n < c_n$ for all $n$,  then $\lim {a_n} =\lim b_n =\lim {c_n} = d$ *does not imply that*  $d < d < d$, but rather $d \leq d \leq d$, which is true.

Comment: How did you check this in your calculator?  (What kind of calculator, what do you enter?)  Are you sure that you didn't check $1 \leq 1 \leq 1$ instead?

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you. I understand better what's happening in the context of the squeeze theorem, but I wonder why my calculator should say 1<1<1 is true, even as it says 1<1 is false. It's a TI-84 pus, I used the logic test

Comment: @P.Gillich In what sense does your calculator say 1<1<1?

Comment: @TobyBartels, I made sure to use strict inequalities in both cases.

Comment: @NoahSchweber  you can test logical statements in the calculator, such as inequalities, equalities, etc, and if the statement is true, the result is 1; if not, the result is 0

Comment: The Squeeze Theorem should be understood as saying that if $a_n \leq b_n \leq c_n$ for all $n$ (or at least eventually in $n$), then $\lim_n a_n = \lim_n b_n = \lim_n c_n$ (if at least $\lim_n a_n = \lim_n c_n$, that is).  In other words, it should always be about weak inequalities.  It's still true if you make the hypothesis $a_n < b_n < c_n$ instead, but that's just making it a slightly less powerful theorem and inviting confusion at the same time.

Comment: @P.Gillich What exactly did you do, with what calculator? It shouldn't be turning up true ...

Comment: I just verified that on a TI-83 Plus (or rather, on the WabbitEmu TI emulator app on my phone) that $1 < 1$ returns $0$ while $1 < 1 < 1$ returns $1$, just like Gillich says.  I have no idea why!

Comment: @NoahSchweber the calculator is a TI-84 Plus. I typed "1", then went to the test menu and inserted a "<", then typed 1 again, inserted another   "<", and then I typed a final "1". One goes into the "Test" menu to select the inequalities/equalities/etc

Comment: Ah,,  $1<1$ returns $0$ and $0<1$ returns $1$, so $(1<1)<1$ would return $1$

Comment: The TI-83 Plus has a TEST menu that allows you to enter $=$, $\ne$, $>$, $\geq$, $<$, and $\leq$.  It also allows you to combine statments with `and`, `or`, `xor`, and `not`.  It may be that it just doesn't do compound inequalities.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Oh wow, so simple! I can't believe it was that the whole time!

Comment: @GrahamKemp, I think that you must be correct.  Gilliam, to test $x < y < z$ with this calculator, you really need to enter $(x < y) \>\mathrm{and}\> (y < z)$.  If you enter $x < y < z$ directly, then (if Graham is right) it's interpreting it as $(x < y) < z$, which is not what we mean at all.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Sorry, I've stolen it ;)

Comment: Actually, you can enter it as $x < y \>\mathrm{and}\> y < z$ (no parentheses); the calculator does the correct order of operations automatically.  (At least on my emulated TI-83 Plus it does.)

Comment: You might want to add a calculator tag to this question (if there is such a tag) and rephrase it to focus on the strange calculator behaviour.  As a question about inequalities, it's pretty trivial (and got downvoted); but as a question about getting a wrong result from a calculator, it's interesting and could help somebody.

Comment: Fair enough, will do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps (in an Occamistic sense) "$<$" is a binary operation that returns $0$ when the thing on the left is larger or equal than the thing on the right, and $1$ otherwise. Therefore, it is safe to assume that the calculator evaluated $$(1<1)<1=0<1=1$$

To test it, try $1<1<-1$.

Comment: $1 < 1 < {}^-1$ comes out as $0$ on my emulated TI-83 Plus, as expected.